# Amplitude of superposition states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, superposition

I have a question about the following chart (for 3 and 4 particles case):

[image]

What does $P_{cycl}$ mean? How's that relevant to the amplitude of superposition states and their symmetricity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The states given in your table seem to be states of a system of N spins in the $\hat{S}^z_{\text{tot}}$ and $\hat{S}^2_{\text{tot}}$ basis which are also eigenstates of the cyclic permutation operator $\hat{P}_{\text{cycl}}$ with $P_{\text{cycl}}$ being the eigenvalue of the cyclic permutation operator.
- An Example definition for the cyclic permutation Operator would be:
  $$\hat{P}_{\text{cycl}}|s_1,...,s_n>=|s_n,s_1,...,s_{n-1}>$$
- You could calculate this explicitly for these states to convince yourself for example:
  $$\hat{P}_{\text{cycl}}(|\uparrow\uparrow\downarrow>+e^{i\frac{2}{3}\pi}|\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow>+e^{-i\frac{2}{3}\pi}|\downarrow\uparrow\uparrow>)=
  |\downarrow\uparrow\uparrow>+e^{i\frac{2}{3}\pi}|\uparrow\uparrow\downarrow>+e^{-i\frac{2}{3}\pi}|\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow>=e^{i\frac{2}{3}\pi}(|\uparrow\uparrow\downarrow>+e^{i\frac{2}{3}\pi}|\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow>+e^{-i\frac{2}{3}\pi}|\downarrow\uparrow\uparrow>)$$
  $$\longrightarrow P_{\text{cycl}}=e^{i\frac{2}{3}\pi}$$
- The $P_{\text{cycl}}$ is just a third quantumnumber you could use to characterise these states. That means if you would have a N-particle Hamitlonian which commutes with the operators $\hat{S}^z_{\text{tot}}$, $\hat{S}^2_{\text{tot}}$ and $\hat{P}_{\text{cycl}}$ the usage of these states as a basis would probably reduce the complexity of your problem.
- To use these states as an orthonormal basis, you need to normalise them. Therefore, $P_{\text{cycl}}$ is in my opinion only relevant for the normalisation of the states concerning the "amplitudes".
- As already discussed these states are "symmetric" under the cyclic permutation operation with different eigenvalues.

I hope this helps you with your understanding.

Jan

Comment: Thanks!! but the superposition of states shouldn't include 'i' and 'exponential, is that right?

Comment: To make this work, that the states in that table are eigenstates of the permutation operator they have to have these complex phases in the superpositions. If you have any concern in quantum mechanics the Hilbert space of a spin is over the field of complex numbers therefore you can have complex numbers in a superposition of states. This happens often when regarding eigenstates of rotational symmetries.

Comment: You could for example try to see if the example above would still work if there is no ‚complex‘ but only for example $|\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow>+|\downarrow\uparrow\uparrow>+|\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow>$. You will see that you wont get the same eigenvalue for $P_{\text{cycl}}$

Comment: In Quantum Mechanics it is completely normal to have complex superpositions of states. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_superposition)

Comment: Thanks! So if I consider the basis of each subspace, then the superposition shouldn't have 'i' and exponential, right?

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to. could you clarify your question? Maybe with an example?

Comment: Yes, if I consider the decomposition of Hilbert space, $1/2⊗1/2⊗1/2⊗1/2=2⊕1⊕1⊕1⊕0⊕0$, then should the basis of each of the subspaces in the right-hand-side look different from those eigenstates of permutation operator in terms of the amplitudes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112977/discussion-between-jan0155-and-zhengrong).